Calculate speed when direction is unknown
I´m trying to solve something that I can maybe best describe as trying to measure the speed of a water ripple when you don´t know the direction the ripple is travelling from and to. This would be impossible if you only measure the time the ripple passes through at two locations, but what if you use three locations that form a right triangle? For this, we assume the ripple is a straight line and not curved.
I can best imagine the problem in a coordinate system as seen below. I have sensor A, B and C. I know their exact position in the coordinate system. A straight line the travels through the coordinate system from any given angle. I will know the exact time the straight line passes each sensor. How do I from this information calculate the equation of the line and then the speed at which the straight line travels?
Coordinate system displaying the problem:

